# Why two Loggers do not split messages according to their levels in Log4j?

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I want to log all logger levels to a file (FATAL-> ALL) and simultaneousy show ERROR level and higher in the console. I'm using root logger to log all levels to a file and separate logger to log ERROR level to a console. My XML configuration file looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                    pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %highlight{%level}{FATAL=bg_red, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow, INFO=blue} %logger{36} - %msg%n" disableAnsi="false"/>
        </Console>

        <File name="File" fileName="output.log" bufferedIO="true" >
            <PatternLayout
                    pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %highlight{%level}{FATAL=bg_red, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow, INFO=blue} %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </File>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="ALL">
            <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
        </Root>

        <Logger name="com.danielk" level="ERROR">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Logger>

    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I expected to have all levels of logging in the file and only "Error" and above level in the console but I have only "Error" levels on both (console and file):

> 23:19:54.422 [main] ERROR com.danielk.Example - error error error from Example
>   23:19:54.434 [main] ERROR com.danielk.Main - ERROR ERROR ERROR FROM MAIN

Messages themselves are correcty build because when I set both loggers (Root and additional) to "ALL" level I can see all kind of messages (not only "Error" level).

What should I do to split levels:

1. File - all levels
2. Console - Errors and above only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ThresholdFilter` on console appender to filter out log events that have `ERROR` or more specific level (https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html#ThresholdFilter).

Entire configuration e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                    pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %highlight{%level}{FATAL=bg_red, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow, INFO=blue} %logger{36} - %msg%n"
                    disableAnsi="false"/>
            <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
        </Console>
        <File name="File" fileName="output.log" bufferedIO="true" append="false">
            <PatternLayout
                    pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %highlight{%level}{FATAL=bg_red, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow, INFO=blue} %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

PS When you specify:

```
<Logger name="com.danielk" level="ERROR">
   <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
</Logger>
```

then log level is set to `ERROR` for all sub-packages and classes inside `com.danielk` (unless you configure more specific logger, say `com.danielk.db.MyClass` with a different level). That's why only errors appeared in the log file.

Comment: Good answer, but I think it's worth noting that logger names are not required to match package and class names - this is merely the expected best practice. So really the level was set to ERROR for the **logger** named "com.danielk" and all **descendant loggers** of that logger. From [Logger Hierarchy](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/architecture.html)

Comment: @Łukasz Thanks for the answer. Summarizing, it only makes sense to create additional loggers (other than generic root logger) when you want to treat  different structures of the project separately(e.g. modules, classes etc.) but NOT for the same structure - so different loging levels directed to different appenders should be done via proper appender configuration...

Comment: @D.B. thanks for your comment could you please be more specific what you meant? As I checked, every loger should have a name (without name property I have comple time error) but not necessarily package name or the name of the class - is this what you meant?

Comment: @Daniel I'm just trying to point out that the logger name **should** in most cases match the fully qualified java class name as this is best practice, but there is no strict requirement that guarantees this is **always** true. Lukasz had written "log level is set to ERROR for all **sub-packages and classes** inside com.danielk" which has the built-in assumption that you're following best practices and naming the logger based on your java package and class names. You probably are doing this, but I wanted to make a distinction between **logger** and **class** names to help you understand log4j2.